# Python3: Crawl JSon and Ignore Non-Existent Key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm parsing received `JSon` from an API and extract it's values. Some API result don't have certain keys, meanwhile the script is already hardcoded to extract the value from the missing key.

I have tried to handle `exception` on each value extraction. It's `try:except` times and starts `try:except` all over the place:

```
#Example 1
if json_response['anoa']['pangea'].get('malaria'):
   print(json_response['anoa']['pangea']['malaria'])

#Example 2
try:
   print(json_response['anoa']['pangea']['malaria'])
except: pass
```

The thing with `try:except` over the entire extraction codes: it's just breaks when got some `exception` and ignore the left-over code and starts from the beginning of loop. Yes, I feed data from a wordlist to the API using loops.

I also tried [fuckitpy](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) to ignore any `exception` but I wanted it to also print the exception and just continue.

```
with fuckit:
    my_shitty_parser
```

Using `fuckitpy` is also equivalent of `try:except` block but it cost less lines. I still `fucking` all over the place. Is there a better way to handle this? I need to extract a lot of key. It is sad to see the script just breaks over 1 unnecessary `exception`.

Comment: Already Tried that ealrlier with `None`, but replacing it with `{}` or `[]` works perfectly. Thank you. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: It may not related, but is `Fastly` supports `Domain Fronting`?

Comment: Ah well xD @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `json_response['anoa']['pangea'].get('malaria')`, try `json_response.get('anoa',{}).get('pangea',{}).get('malaria', None]` because if you're not guaranteed that `anoa` or `pangea` etc. exist, you'll want to have a fallback in place for when they don't. And to make sure your chains work as expected, make sure to match the fallback to the kind of data you were expecting. E.g. if it's an object on the JSON side, use an empty dict as fallback, if it's an array on the JSON side, use an empty list as fallback, etc.